# Iterating over an object in a Google Apps script and printing to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, firebase, google-sheets

I'm having trouble printing more than one row to my google sheet with this loop.

The first row appends fine, but I want the function to append all objects from the data var.

The data object is properly pulling from Firebase when I verify with a Logger.

```
var firebaseUrl = "https://test.firebaseio.com/alerts"; 
var secret = "sssssssssssssssssssss"; 
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret); 
var data = base.getData();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("feed");
var selection = sheet.getActiveRange();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var columns = selection.getNumColumns();
var rows = selection.getNumRows();
var num = 2;

function writeToSheets() {  
  for(var i in data) {
    var values = [
      [ data[i].id, data[i].two, data[i].three, data[i].four ]
    ];
    var keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
    var sheetRow = [];
    var entryKeys;
    for (j in keys) {
      sheetRow = [];
      entryKeys = Object.keys(values[keys[j]])
      for (k in entryKeys) {
        sheetRow.push(values[keys[j]][entryKeys[k]]);
      }
      sheet.appendRow(sheetRow);                            
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what the structure of the object `data` is.  Give a sample of what it looks like.  Also, these two statements make no sense to me:  `var values = [[ data[i].id, data[i].two, data[i].three, data[i].four ]];var keys = Object.keys(values[0]);`  It looks like `values[0]` returns an ID, not an object.  The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.  What is it actually returning?

Comment: `data` is JSON coming from Firebase. `var values`  identifies which items in `data` to pull from Firebase.

Comment: shouldn't appendRow in some way be async?

Comment: JSON can be configured in many different ways, with multiple inner levels of data.  You need to debug your code.  Put in some `Logger.log()` statements to see what the code is actually doing.  Like: `for(var i in data) {Logger.log("i: " + i)`  Run the code and then VIEW the LOGS.  That will print `i` to the log every time your outer most loop runs.  For all I know, it's only looping once.  There is no way we can know without seeing an example of `data`  I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried this code (assuming that I guessed the data structure correctly):

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = [ 
    {'id': 1, 'two': 'test2', 'three': 'test3', 'four': 'test4'},
    {'id': 2, 'two': 'test2-2', 'three': 'test3-2', 'four': 'test4-2'}
  ]

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("feed");
  var selection = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var columns = selection.getNumColumns();
  var rows = selection.getNumRows();
  var num = 2;

  function writeToSheets() {  
    for(var i in data) {
      var values = [
        [ data[i].id, data[i].two, data[i].three, data[i].four ]
      ];
      var keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
      var sheetRow = [];
      var entryKeys;
      for (j in keys) {
        sheetRow = [];
        entryKeys = Object.keys(values[keys[j]])
        for (k in entryKeys) {
          sheetRow.push(values[keys[j]][entryKeys[k]]);
        }
        sheet.appendRow(sheetRow);                            
      }
    }
  }

  writeToSheets();
}
```

When I run it, it fails after printing the first line with an error `TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type undefined. (line 26, file "Code")`.
And it is easy to see what exactly happens if you run it in debug mode:

- You have `values` array with one element (line 18)
- The `var keys = Object.keys(values[0]);` becomes [0,1,2,3] (we have 4 values inside the first element of `values` array)
- Then, having j from 0 to 3 we get `entryKeys = Object.keys(values[keys[j])`

  - When j = 0, values[keys[j]] = values[0] - we get the first element from `values`
  - When j = 1, values[keys[j]] = values[1] - here we fail, because there is only 1 element in `values`

I am not really sure what you are trying to do here with all these keys, but if you just want to print the data, it can be done simpler:

```
  function writeToSheets() {  
    for(var i in data) {
      var item = data[i];
      sheetRow = [];
      for (key in item) {
        sheetRow.push(item[key]);
      }
      sheet.appendRow(sheetRow);                            
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Boris! Your new writeToSheets function did the trick. I was definitely over thinking the problem, ha. Cheers!